# React Typescript Component: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Test` component that is class-based and connects to redux so it can stay aware of the app state.

```
// ./components/test.tsx

import { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { AppState } from "../redux/store";

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
      super(props);
    }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
    getVal: state.chat
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

I want to be able to make many instances of this class-based component `Test`. I have a button that should make a new instance of the `Test` class each time its clicked, notice that I'm not adding the component to the DOM, this is intentional. also that I am creating the class-based component from within a functional component this could be changed if it makes an difference.

```
import React from "react";
import Test from "./components/test";

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const makeNewTest = () => {
    const newTest1 = new Test('im new');
//                   ^ error
    const newTest2 = new Test('im new too');
//                   ^ error
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={makeNewTest}>Make new tests</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export { App };
```

The error I get is `'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)`

**What am I trying to do?**
The application presents the user with a number of "actions" to choose from, once an action is added, it can then be configured and connected to another action. The configuration of one action will affect the other actions connected to it.

An example of an "action" could be a timer, the user selects the timer action to add it, then they can configure the timer to repeat every 4 seconds. 
Any other "action" that connects to this timer needs to know when the 4 seconds is up. 
As an example of a component that connects to the timer, we could have an "action" called fetch, the fetch action can be configured to fetch data from an API, and can be connected to a timer action. Each time the timer fires after 4 seconds the fetch action gets the data from the API.

So my plan is to have a number of classes for the timer and fetch actions etc, as the users add them I would save the class to an array in redux, which would represent all the classes the user has added. When the user wants to configure the class, Id finds the class in the array and update it.

When the timer reaches 4 seconds the fetch needs to go out to the api. The example I made above shows a number of classes being made, and each of them trying to get state from redux as a simple proof of concept.

Comment: That's because `connect` returns function, not a class.. The whole setup looks a bit weird, why `Test` extends `Component`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the class to be able to access the redux state, so when the app state changes, the class can react to the change, I want to be able to create many classes with this functionality.

Comment: this link shows a class-based component connecting to redux https://kyleshevlin.com/renderless-components

Comment: I think **what** you want to do can be achieved with `useEffect` but we don't know what you want to do because your question only explains **how** you want to do it.

Comment: let me add this detail to the question, thank you for your guidance